# How to fire window.onresize event?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to fire the resize event on window programmatically:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
evt.initEvent('resize', true, false);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

That unfortunately does not work. I am trying to make ExtJS library to do recalculations, and it uses DOM Level 3 events so I cannot just call `window.onresize();`.

Comment: I don't know ExtJS very well, but in jQuery it is trivial to fire a resize event by doing `$(window).resize();` because jQuery has it's own event abstraction. Doesn't ExtJS has something similar you can use?

Comment: Wait, *why* can't you just do `window.onresize()`?

Comment: TypeError: window.onresize is not a function

Comment: @sdleihssirhc This would only work if you attach the event the DOM0 way.

Answer (score 28):

You are creating the wrong event.

Resize is a UIEvent, [read the specs here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-resize)

You need to do this:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false,window,0);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/9hsBA/

Comment: That seems to work on JSFiddle, but when I run it in WebKit Inspector console, ExtJS application does not layout. Nothing happens. It layouts if I resize the browser window manually.

Comment: In that case ExtJS does not use DOM level 3 events like you stated, but since i don't know ExtJS i have no idea how their implementation is.

Comment: I've been looking for this solution for a while and to understand why resize() wasn't working. Thank you very much indeed.

Answer (score 4):

In case createEvent might get [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createEvent) in favor of [CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent), here's a similar snippet using the CustomEvent API:

```
var ev = new CustomEvent('resize'); //instantiate the resize event
ev.initEvent('resize');

window.dispatchEvent(ev); // fire 'resize' event!
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else needs this, in Extjs 4.1 you can do something typically inelegant...

```
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewport')[0].doLayout();
```

No need for an id on the viewport - the .query('viewport') part is using the viewport's alias config.