# Creating CodeMirror dynamically - rendering issues

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I recently started to develop a class that manipulates over CodeMirror - dynamically links necessary libraries, provides comunication with server and so on.
Because of that I hold everything in variables, and upon initialisation, the CodeMirror is appended to DOM node which is not within document tree. Just like that:

```
 var holder = document.createElement("div");  
 var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");     
 holder.appendChild(textarea);
 this.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(textarea, {/*options*/});
```

Then I append the DIV myself when `.show()` method is called upon my class:

```
 this.show(node) {
   if(this.editor!=null) {
     node.parentNode.replaceChild(holder,node);
   }
 }
```

The editor is OK since  click into it and try to draw, or after I resize window. But before, I just see blank area with disabled scroll bar. I believe this is because of way I initialise whole CodeMirror.
So what should I do to make it work, if I want to keep my class structure?
[Link to live code](http://u8.8u.cz//crap/editor/index.php) (not for IE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more direct way would be to call `.refresh()` on the CodeMirror instance after showing it. See http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#refresh

Answer (score 0):

So I solved the issue very simply - I dispatch `onresize` event after adding editor to dom tree:

```
node.parentNode.replaceChild(holder,node);
var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false,window,0);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Based on [How to dispatch resize event?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622176/607407) question.