# How we canfire a window resize event with XTK?

Tags: xtk

How we can fire a window resize event with XTK?
ANd is it possible to extract the width and the higth of the image witch is into the canvas ?

Best,
AMAL

Answer (score 0):

The resize event is just a general resize event like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7622176/1183453

```
var evt = document.createEvent('UIEvents');
evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false,window,0);
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```